# OpenCL: Additional directories for header files

Tags: opencl, specifications

The OpenCL specification writes in **5.6.3 Build Options**:

#### 5.6.3.1 Preprocessor options

```
...  
-I dir  
    Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched  
    for header files.
```

Can someone please explain what that means? As far as I know you cannot inlcude header files into your OpenCL kernels. So what could this options be for?

EDIT: Link to the OpenCL spec: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf

EDIT2: I was under the **wrong** assumption that it is not allowed to include header files into ones OpenCL kernel. Now I know better, thanks to jHackTheRipper.

Comment: If I have header file,which has some functions implimentations  and should be encluded in several kernels(I mean these function are auxilary in all kernels and I don`t want to duplicate the code)

How I make this inclusions - can I remain the functions in header?Will the kernels and the header functions  be compiled?

Can you specify (may be by example) how I use the "-I" option in these case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows you to add some directories containing header files which are not in the standard include-search path. This way you can tell the compiler where those particular header files are located on your system.

For instance, suppose the file foo.h is not in the standard include path (commonly `/usr/include` on a Unix system), but rather in `/home/foo/my_headers/foo.h`, you can ask the compiler to search /home/foo/my_headers for header files by doing:

```
g++ -I/home/foo/my_headers foo.c -o foo
```

To be complete, the section title introduce the word preprocessor which is the program called before the compiler to replace all `#something` directives by their equivalent. `#include <foo.h>` will be replaced by the content of the `foo.h` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think it does not match the question. I was asking about the OpenCL language (an extension to C). I am curious why there IS such a flag for the OpenCL compiler since it is not allowed to include headers in OpenCL kernel files.

Comment: Sorry but it's totally the same! Don't worry I know about OpenCL compiling on the fly, but the two or three times I had to use it I didn't encounter the fact that header files couldn't be included in OpenCL kernels.

Comment: You are right. I tried including header files into my kernel and it works. Wow, how could I miss that?!

Comment: Happy to have helped you ^^ Just imagine that GPU kernels are kind of equivalent to CPU programs. And when you compile the latter, you need to have all the functions you use defined. So why would it be different with GPU programming?

Answer (score 0):

I include the headers for development, but for releases I process all of the headers and dependencies into one file, and then embed that source in the binary.

Comment: Actually, I am doing the same. Except I always include the kernels as string resources into the binary. I have a small script which is triggered by the makefile. It converts the kernel *.cl files into char pointers which I pass to clBuildProgramWithSource() API.